# How to resolve aspect ratio/scale issue with Javascript/CSS photo gallery script (Ninja Slider/Menucool)?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, scale, aspect-ratio

I am a paid user of the [Ninja Slider](http://www.menucool.com/responsive-slider) and [Thumbnail Carousel](http://www.menucool.com/jquery-slider) scripts and I am attempting to implement a [Flickr-like Slideshow (Demo 4)](http://www.menucool.com/slider/flickr-like-slideshow). Unfortunately, the developer apparently is no longer offering support, not even paid support — it appears that they likely are shutting down entirely — and I am optimistic that someone on Stackoverflow has encountered these CSS or Javascript issues or similar ones and can help. Work in progress is [here](https://travelgasm.com/barcelona-catalonia/barcelona-photos/test/index.html).

The two issues are:

(1) In full-screen mode, when viewed smaller than around 800px, it throws the slideshow down to the bottom of the page and isn’t viewable at all by default until you scroll down.

It should be possible to adjust the size in the responsive settings at the bottom of the ninja-slider-gallery.css or thumbnail-slider-gallery.css files, but resizing the elements alone changes the size, but does not change its placement.

```
/*Responsive settings*/
@media only screen and (max-width:800px){

/*Responsive settings*/
@media only screen and (max-width:736px){
```

What is the best way to modify the CSS so that the gallery is viewable by default on small displays and properly centered like on larger displays?

(2) Also an issue in full-screen mode on smaller devices, it seems to be scaling for width, but not for height. So, on a small display, the image/carousel can extend past the bottom of the screen.

I have reviewed [this helpful post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css) (which has been great for resolving past scale-related issues), gone through the [provided documentation](http://www.menucool.com/responsive-slider) and I have read [this answer](http://www.menucool.com/5781/Make-the-slider-take-the-entire-browser-size) on the developer's site, as well. I have looked at the [code on Demo 8](http://www.menucool.com/slider/show-image-gallery-on-modal-popup) (which does what I would like when in full screen mode), but there must be something I have missed.

Trying to alter the aspectRatio in the Javascript file (like Demo 8), doesn’t work for Demo 4, unfortunately.

What is the best way to modify the CSS or Javascript so that in full-screen mode, the gallery scales to fit on smaller displays — like a mobile turned landscape — in both directions? Not just width, but height, too?

Thank you very much.